# How can I use ExtendedProperties on a DataRow

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow, extended-properties

A C# DataTable has a PropertyCollection `ExtendedProperties`.  A DataColumn in that table also has an `ExtendedProperties`  Why would DataRow not have this?

So, for example, If I have multiple tables and want to add some metadata to be used in the view, I could do something like this:

```
tbl.ExtendedProperties["class"] = "pandas";
tbl.Columns["name"].ExtendedProperties["class"] = "highlighted";
```

How could I go another level further and do something like

```
tbl.Rows[0].ExtendedProperties["class"] = "highlighted";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating your derived version of DataRow and DataTable

```
    [Serializable]
public class CustomDataTable : DataTable
{
    public CustomDataTable()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public CustomDataTable(string tableName)
        : base(tableName)
    {
    }

    public CustomDataTable(string tableName, string tableNamespace)
        : base(tableName, tableNamespace)
    {
    }

    protected override Type GetRowType()
    {
        return typeof (CustomDataRow);
    }

    protected override DataRow NewRowFromBuilder(DataRowBuilder builder)
    {
        return new CustomDataRow(builder);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class CustomDataRow : DataRow
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> _extendedProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public Dictionary<string, object> ExtendedProperties {
        get { return _extendedProperties; }
    }

    public void SetAttribute(string name, object value)
    {
        ExtendedProperties.Add(name, value);
    }

    public CustomDataRow()
        : base(null)
    {
    }

    public CustomDataRow(DataRowBuilder builder)
        : base(builder)
    {
    }
}
```